# UNIX: psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, unix, postgres.app

When I type 'psql' into terminal, or when I try to connect to the server using Postgres.app I get

```
"/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/psql" -p5432 -d "postgres"
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory".
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/Users/Dimitar/postgres/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

However, when I type "psql -p 5432 -h localhost", I successfully connect. Can someone please tell me why that is the case. I've looked everywhere online and most people with a similar issue cannot get "psql -p 5432 -h localhost" to work as it does for me.

Here are the processes that show up including the word "post"

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as1Nf.png)

Comment: A space is required after `-p`.  Otherwise, it seems like the port number would get interpreted as an option by `psql` command.

Comment: The first line is generated by Postgres.app. I installed Postgresql with homebrew as well and when I type "psql" into terminal, the first line is not present, but the other three are, so its safe to assume that is not the problem.